# Issue with Kendo Grid. The confirmation message is not updating

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using the Kendo Grid to list user data.  An issue has been discovered.  When a user clicks the delete button, a verification message comes up stating, "Are you user you want to delete, user Joe Blow".  If I click cancel, and try a different user "Sally Smith", the error message will be, "Are you user you want to delete, user Joe Blow".  I checked the function and the correct data is going into function.

I went through the code in Chrome debugger and I found out that the error message is coming back from code on: https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/js/kendo.all.js

I do have a function that resets the values to "".  However, the data is not getting update when it goes to kendo.all.js.  How can I reset the data when it goes there?

Here is my code for the button:

```
template: '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="confirmDelete(\'#=ExternalId#\', \'#=FirstName#\', \'#=LastName#\', \'#=EmailAddress#\')" style="padding: .25rem;">X</button>',
```

Here is my code for the delete function:

```
var confirmDelete = function (eid, firstN, lastN, emailA) {
        var dialog = $("#delete-confirm-modal");
        externalId = eid;
        firstName = firstN;
        lastName = lastN;
        emailAddress = emailA;

        if (dialog.data("kendoDialog")) {
            dialog.data("kendoDialog").open();
        } else {
            dialog.kendoDialog({
                width: "450px",
                title: "Confirm delete",
                closable: true,
                modal: true,
                content: "<p>Confirm that you wish to delete user " + firstName + " " + lastName + "(" + emailAddress + "). Once this is done, it cannot be reversed.</p>",
                actions: [
                    {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        primary: true
                    }, {
                        text: "Confirm",
                        action: function (e) {
                            var url = "/apic/usermaintenance/deleteuser/" + externalId;
                            $.get(url,
                                function (data) {
                                    //$("#userListGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read;
                                    //$("#userListGrid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();

                                    /*$('#userListGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read().then(function () {
                                        $('#userListGrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
                                    });*/

                                    KendoGridRefresh();
                                    
                                    kendo.alert("User has been deleted");
                                }).fail(function () {
                                    kendo.alert("Unable to delete user. An error has occured. Please try again.");
                                });
                                                                               }
                    }
                ],
                close: onClose
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first click you are initializing dialog, on second click you are opening already initialized dialog with old content.

You need to update content of dialog:

```
    if (dialog.data("kendoDialog")) {
        dialog.data("kendoDialog").content("<p>Confirm that you wish to delete user " + firstName + " " + lastName + "(" + emailAddress + "). Once this is done, it cannot be reversed.</p>");
        dialog.data("kendoDialog").open();
    }
```

Example: [update content](https://dojo.telerik.com/AXUjABuh)

Comment: I ran into an error with your example. However, I made the following edit and it worked for me: 
            dialog.data("kendoDialog").content("<p>Confirm that you wish to delete user " + firstName + " " + lastName + "(" + emailAddress + "). Once this is done, it cannot be reversed.</p>");

Comment: Oh yea, dialog is just an instance of jquery element, I edited answer. Should work now